# Attribute ng-model not allowed here

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webstorm

I am trying to use the ng-model attribute on a dropdown, however WebStorm keeps telling that it is not allowed. When I run the app, it is not bound so I thinking it has do with my Angular version. I am running the latest version, and ng-model seems to work on all other elements besides select. Has something changed within the last update?

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="selectPost" class="control-label">Posts</label>
    <select ng-model="post" class="form-control" id="selectPost" >
        <option ng-repeat="post in currentUser.posts" value="{{post._id}}">
            {{post.name}}
        </option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: not being bound is often a result of breaking the rule of not passing object to `ng-model` ....always have a ***dot*** in `ng-model`!

Comment: this should work, though there are a couple style considerations in this code that might be creating a challenge;  first, you should *always* be binding to an object instead of a primitive whenever possible; second, your `ng-model` property and `ng-repeat` property are named the same, which may cause an issue; and lastly, you should consider using `ng-options` rather than `ng-repeat`.

Comment: Thanks guys, I think it had to do with using ng-repeat vs ng-options.

Answer (score 5):

change `ng-model` into `data-ng-model`,
it is a known WebStorm bug

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the solution to your problem, but I was getting "not allowed here" for a lot Angular attributes inexplicably.

It turned out that I had excluded the folder that included the angular.js from my project so that it didn't bother me with my normal day to day. It meant that the page worked fine when created but Webstorm wasn't able to read it as I was writing the code

Comment: How did you include angular.js (or any file) in your project?

Comment: That was my problem as well. Mark `node_modules/@angular` as not excluded and the problem goes away

Comment: @rpadovani Isn't that for Angular? Commentor is requesting for AngularJS 1.x

Comment: @Edric you are totally right :) Well, then I had this problem with Angular, and I fixed as I mentioned in my first comment!

Comment: It also works with AngularJS. In my case I marked the `bower_components/angular` folder as not excluded and it finally worked again.